# C# console program questions regarding instantiation and use of static fields

Tags: c#, instantiation, output

C# newbie here.  I recently took a test that asked what the out put of some C# code was.  I don't have the exact code but I've tried to recreate it from memory below.  This code doesn't compile for some reason(not all that important since I just have questions about what is happening here).  The part I had the most issues trying to remember were the lines creating all the class fields.

Here are my questions:

1. Is creating a new instance of a class using "new class1();" without assigning it to a variable a valid way to instantiate it?
2. Each time the class is instantiated how are the static fields handled?
3. Can you even create class fields by calling the constructor?

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;

   namespace CustomFunctionTest
   {
       class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               new class1();
               new class1("E");
            }
       }
       public class class1
       {

           public static class1 test1 = new class1("A");
           private class1 b = new class1("B");
           public static class1 c = new class1("C");

           public class1()
           {
               Console.WriteLine("D");
           }
           public class1(string str)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(str);
           }

       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is creating a new instance of a class using "new class1();" without assigning it to a variable a valid way to instantiate it?

Yes. It's constructor could perform some action on static objects, or even be retained somehow. Or, it could just be garbage collected. Good for quality code? Not usually.

> 2) Each time the class is instantiated how are the static fields handled?

If there is a static constructor, static fields are initialized before the static constructor when the type is being initialized and the type is only initialized once. In your example, there is no static constructor, so the runtime defers the initialization if the static fields until they are accessed.

> 3) Can you even create class fields by calling the constructor?

Yes. A class's fields are usually initialized when the class is constructed.

Comment: Your second point is true when a static constructor is explicitly defined, however when there is no static constructor (as in the OP's example) the initialization of static fields may be deferred by the runtime until the first time they are accessed. See: http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/14/static-constructors-part-three/

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes; for the compiler or JITTER to, in general, determine that no side-effects occurred in the class constructor is too complex a problem to contemplate, so it cannot be optimized out.
2. The type must be completely, and successfully, initialized before any instance constructors can run. The exact sequence in which static constructors and field initializers is configurable, and has had varying default orders in different version of the DOT NET framework.
3. When any constructor has completed a valid instance of the class object is returned; however, this does not mean that the instance is necessarily "ready for action". e-serialization, for instance, often relies on running default constructors followed by setting all non-default properties to create an instance that is truly "ready for use".